# How to write a back-relating dominant in 4 parts

Tags: voice-leading

In this exercise I am asked to harmonize a figured bass and explain the V - ii6 in bar 3 - 4. Since ii  chords usually come before dominant chords I paged through my textbook to see what the question meant. Apparently this would be a back relating dominant. I am not sure how to write this though and not sure how to explain it. It has something to do with the dominant chord not really sounding like a dominant chord enough for it to need to resolve... or at least this what I understand. So if the resolution of the cadential 64 in bar 3 is on a weaker beat then would that make moving to ii6 acceptable? Is this what a back relating dominant is? Can someone please explain it to me and help by seeing my solution to the given figured bass and tell me if this would be a correct solution?

[image]

here is the original question in my textbook

[image]

Comment: Just a comment, because I only Googled the term. BRD is for a _prolongation_ of the preceding chord. So this `V6/4 5/3` is apparently prolonging the preceding `I6` before connecting to `ii6 I6 ii`. Without the prolonging BRD, it would apparently be only `I6 ii6 I6 ii`.

Comment: What is this exercise? I can't even explain the ii6-I6!

Comment: @Dekkadeci, `ii6 I6` would just be parallel 6/3 chords, you can just move them by step. I think it's more typical to have them descend by step.

Comment: @armani, Ottman's _Elementary Harmony_ has a similar prolongation rule of thumb for the tonic chord, although it's not written with that specific wording: "`I` may progress to any other chord. Any chord may progress to `I` when `I` interrupts a progression listed in this table (e.g., `ii-I-V`)" Ottman essentially is using "interrupt" for "prolong", and basically he is saying `I` can be inserted anywhere into any standard progression. It's a bit like the tonic chord version of this BRD rule of thumb. Two ways to prolong a basic progression.

Comment: @MichaelCurtis - Huh, none of the resources I was exposed to in my Royal Conservatory of Music theory lessons ever mentioned that rule of thumb in that Ottman work. I think there's a chance that RCM actively distrusted that Ottman work.

Comment: @Dekkadeci, I can't account for the RCM, but I quoted the 2nd edition, p. 187, it's a table called "the commonly used chord progressions." https://kupdf.net/download/robert-w-ottman-elementary-harmony-theory-and-practice_59c3eb0f08bbc5c5126870ff_pdf

Comment: dekka ii6 I6 ii is just a prolongation of ii... in those three chords the I6 does not function as a tonic chord. Michael: How does one write the cadential V64 after the I6 so that we can say that it is prolonging the I6 instead of being a new chord function?

Comment: Can you add the actual figured bass of the assignment? Also, does this book follow the convention of `V6/4` rather than `I6/4` for the tonic chord in second inversion?

Comment: Michael. Added. The book uses the V6/4 label for cadential 6/4s. I have not yet come across another 64 chord yet in the book so not sure.